# Double-click wrong behaviour at jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, double-click

Good day!

i have a jTable, i am filling it by JButton listener.
after jTable is filled by mouse double-click i invoke JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.
After that problem is accured. After clicking on JButton again jTable is filled again. And if i double click on row\cell again it will show me 2 messages by JOptionPane instead of one.
As i understand i need to refresh model but i didn`t success.

My code:

Form.java

```
    btnExec = new JButton("Exec");
    table = new JTable();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
    // Create Button Listener
    ActionListener startProcess = new ExecButtonPressed();
    btnExec.addActionListener(startProcess);
```

ExecButtonPressed.java

```
public class ExecButtonPressed implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                System.out.println("table rows:" + Form.table.getRowCount());
                DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
                prepare(tableModel); // create headers
                fill(tableModel);   // add rows

                Form.table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
                Form.table.setModel(tableModel);

                sortresize(Form.table); //resize width of columns + sort by id desc
                Form.table.setDefaultEditor(Object.class, null);


                DoubleClicker.whattodo(); // class of double-click behavior logic


            }catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

//
    private void prepare(DefaultTableModel tableModel) throws Exception {
        try {
            tableModel.addColumn("id");
            tableModel.addColumn("name");
            tableModel.addColumn("age");
        }catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


//
    private void fill(DefaultTableModel tableModel) {
        Object [] line = {"01", "Qw" , "20"};
        tableModel.addRow(line);
        Object [] line2 = {"02", "As" , "21"};
        tableModel.addRow(line2);
        Object [] line3 = {"03", "Zx" , "22"};
        tableModel.addRow(line3);
    }

//
    private void sortresize(JTable table) {
        //Resize width
        for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
            TableColumn tableColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column);
            if (column  == 0) {
                tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( 45 ); 
            } else if (column   == 1){
                tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( 50 ); 
            } else if (column   == 2){
                tableColumn.setPreferredWidth( 55 ); 
            } 
        }


        //Sort table.
        if (table.getRowCount() > 1){
            TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
            table.setRowSorter(sorter);
            List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();

            int columnIndexToSort = 0;
            sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndexToSort, SortOrder.DESCENDING));

            sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
            sorter.sort();
        };

    }

//  

}
```

DoubleClicker.java

```
public class DoubleClicker {

    public static void whattodo() {
        Form.table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent)  {
                try {
                    System.out.println("click:" + mouseEvent.getClickCount());
                    Form.table = (JTable) mouseEvent.getSource();
                    Point point = mouseEvent.getPoint();
                    int row = Form.table.rowAtPoint(point);
                    int columnid = Form.table.columnAtPoint(point);

                    Form.table.convertRowIndexToModel(row);
                    Form.table.convertColumnIndexToModel(columnid);

                    if (mouseEvent.getClickCount() == 2 && Form.table.getSelectedRow() != -1) {
                        if (Form.table.getColumnName(columnid).equalsIgnoreCase("name")) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
                              (String) Form.table.getValueAt(row,columnid), "Selected name", 1);
                        }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried different options like

```
tableModel.setRowCount(0); 
tableModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements(); 
tableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
```

maybe i put it in wrong place?
because every **mouse click is registered twice** at 2nd button execution.

---

**Update:**
i added

```
System.out.println("table rows:" + Form.table.getRowCount());
```

right after public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
and as i can see in console, Form.table.getRowCount() == 3 after second button execution.
Also added

```
System.out.println("click:" + mouseEvent.getClickCount());
```

as the first line of public void mousePressed(MouseEvent mouseEvent)
as i can see, after 2nd button execution in every click on table is done twice
i got :
click:1
click:1
at the first execution it`s just click:1

It seems like there is one view after another.

the entire Form.java in case someone would be generous to compile

```
    public class Form {

    private JFrame frame;
    public static JTable table;
    public static JButton btnExec;
    public static JScrollPane scrollPane;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Form window = new Form();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Form() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        btnExec = new JButton("Exec");
        btnExec.setBounds(10, 11, 89, 23);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnExec);

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 45, 369, 174);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);


        // Create Button Listener
        ActionListener startProcess = new ExecButtonPressed();
        btnExec.addActionListener(startProcess);




    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t know if this is the cause of your problem, but… you are ignoring the values returned by `convertRowIndexToModel` and `convertColumnIndexToModel`.  Which means those calls are essentially doing nothing.

Comment: @VGR, it's not the case, i can even write:
     

`int row = Form.table.convertRowIndexToView(Form.table.convertRowIndexToModel(Form.table.rowAtPoint(point)));
           

int columnid =  Form.table.convertColumnIndexToView(Form.table.convertColumnIndexToModel(Form.table.columnAtPoint(point)));`

result would be the same

Comment: Found out work around, not so sure how good it is in general, but.

Since Form.table.getRowCount() == 3 even before button is clicked the 2nd time,
I transfered `table = new JTable();
   scrollPane.setViewportView(table);` from Form.java to ExecButtonPressed.java , as the first lines : `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           try { Form.table = new JTable();
               Form.scrollPane.setViewportView(Form.table);`. so every time after button is clicked jtable object is recreated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer at coderanch forum, decided to submit it there.
maybe some one will need it in the future.

> The solution is to add the MouseListener should be added to the table when you create the table (not in the actionPerformed() method of the ActionListener).

so i've transfer `DoubleClicker.whattodo(); // class of double-click behavior logic` from ExecButtonPressed.java to Form.java:

```
table = new JTable();
scrollPane.setViewportView(Form.table);
DoubleClicker.whattodo(); // class of double-click behavior logic
```